# Node JS: How to catch the individual errors while reading files, in case multiple files are read on Promise.all?

Tags: node.js, fs, readfile

I am having 10 different files and I need to read their content and merge it in one object (in NodeJS). I am successfully doing that with the code below:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { promisify } = require("util");    
const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile);

let filePathArray = ['path/to/file/one', ... , 'path/to/file/ten'];
Promise.all(
  filePathArray.map(filePath => {          
    return readFileAsync(filePath);
  })
).then(responses => { //array of 10 reponses
  let combinedFileContent = {};
    responses.forEach((itemFileContent, index) => {
      let tempContent = JSON.parse(itemFileContent);
      //merge tempContent into combinedFileContent 
    }
});
```

But what I wonder is, how to catch if there is some error while trying to read the files? When reading a single file, this works like:

```
fs.readFile(singleFilePath, (singleFileErr, singleFileContent) => {
  if (singleFileErr) {
    //do something on error, while trying to read the file        
  }
});
```

So my question here is, how can I access to the error inn the first code snippet, which corresponds to `singleFileErr` from this  second code snippet?
The issue I am facing is: in case some of the files does not exists, I want to check the error and to skip this file, but since I can not detect the error with current implementation, my whole block crashes and I am not able to merge the other 9 files because of this one. I want to use the error check I mentioned in the second snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) function, which will run every `Promise` passed to it, and will tell you at the end which ones succeeded and which ones failed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this:

- in the `map()` callback, return a promise that resolves to `null` if the file is not found.
- Introduce a middle stage in the promise chain filtering out `null` responses.

This would look something like this:

```
Promise.all(
  filePathArray.map(filePath => {          
    return readFileAsync(filePath).catch(function(error){
      if(isErrorFileDoesNotExist(error)) return null
      throw error;
    })
  });
).then(responses => {
   return responses.filter(response => response != null) 
})
.then(filteredResponses => { 
  // .. do something
});
```

Would that work for you? Note this presupposes you are actually able to discriminate between missing file errors from other errors the promise returned by `readFileAsync()` may reject - presumably via the `isErrorFileDoesNotExist()` function in this snippet.